# Value of ajax function is returned later

Tags: jquery, ajax

Since AJAX function is executing after the main function, **pos** always returns value 0 and am not able to fetch the actual value.

How can I execute ajax function before the main function

```
    var pos = 0;
jQuery(function ($) {
  jQuery.ajax({
        url: wpws_ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
             dataType: 'json',
               cache: false,
        data: {
            action: 'getData',
               key: Id
        },
        success: function(pos){
                        pos = JSON.parse(pos)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, text, status) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + " Error");
    }
    });
});
/*main function starts here*/
jQuery(function ($) {

    if (pos)
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (typeof demo !== "undefined") {
        demo.setCurrentTime(pos);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Please, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `async:false` in ajax call solved my issue. Many Thanks to [Nishant Solanki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835912/nishant-solanki) :)

Answer (score 0):

Both Looks main. keep your AJAX in specific function with name. for eg:

```
function MyAJAX() {
   //your AJAX Function
}
```

call `MyAJAX()` inside main function. it will give required `POS` value.

/*main function starts here*/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    MyAJAX()    
    if (pos)
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (typeof demo !== "undefined") {
        demo.setCurrentTime(pos);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jQuery Promises.

```
var pos = 0;
var function = getPos(){
  var getPosDfd = $.Deferred();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: wpws_ajaxurl,
    type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
    data: {
        action: 'getData',
           key: theWebinarId
    },
    success: function(pos){
                    getPosDfd.resolve();
                    pos = JSON.parse(pos)
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, text, status) {
    getPosDfd.reject();
    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + " Error");
    }
});
return getPosDfd.promise();
}
```

And now where you are accessing the value of pos.

```
getPos().done(function(){
    if (pos)
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (typeof demo !== "undefined") {
        demo.setCurrentTime(pos);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do your ajax call inside your main function, and check "pos" value inside "success" ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do your ajax request like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: ... ,
    type: ... ,
    data: ... 
}).done(function() {
    // change the value of 'pos' if necessary
    // call your main function
});
```

because `done` is executed only when the ajax request has returned something